# UINavigationbar with a custom background image

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, categories

I have a custom category to define a special background image for my navigationbar depending on the view I'm in.

Within the category I set the image using

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

The thing is, when navigating through my views in the Navigation Controller, the custom image disappears leaving a blank white space 320x44(size of the bar) until the next controller reappers - i.e. after about 1 second.

This sort of looks ugly and I was wondering whether there was a better way to do this so I have a clean implementation which looks nice aswell and fits my demands.

Thanks in advance.

Category Code:

```
- (void)initImageDictionary
   {
     if(navigationBarImages==NULL){
      navigationBarImages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }   
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *imageName = [navigationBarImages objectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: self]];

    UIImage *image = imageName;
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

}


- (void)setMyImage:(UIImage*)image 
{
[navigationBarImages setObject:image forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: self]];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then I call:

```
[self.navigationBar performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setMyImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageTopbar]];
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have implemented to get better idea?

Comment: added some code, hope it helps.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383873/approach-to-make-a-custom-tabbar

Comment: checked it but it basically is about uitabbar and alternative options. did u intend me to hint at the latter? also, the link provided hold nothing about my problem.

Comment: You shouldn't call `setMyImage:` in a background thread. UIKit isn't threadsafe, so the delay could very well be a side effect of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIKit only on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController, try this where @"BGimage.png" is your image file:

//puts an image as bg pattern(tiles) for a View
//self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BGimage.png"]];